# How can I show my scriptlet value inside the tabpanel of Struts2 jQuery

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, struts2

Am not getting any error ,but my date (<%=date%) is not showing inside the `<sj:tab>`, is their any way so that i can show the database(date) value inside the `<sj:tbbedpanel>.....</sj:tabpanel>`

---

I tried this in my JSP Page, but it is not showing values in TabPanel

```
<sj:tabbedpanel id="remotetabs"  selectedTab="2" animate="true" collapsible="true" sortable="true">
<s:url id="remoteurl3" action="NewRoutineOpr"/>
<sj:tab id="tab3" href="%{remoteurl3}" label="Day"  closable="true" targets="maindiv">
</sj:tab>
</sj:tabbedpanel>
```

Comment: why you using scrip-let while same can be done with S2 tags in clean way

Comment: I do not know Struts 2 tags more, This is my first project in struts 2. Please tell me the relevent struts 2 tag for this above question.

Comment: Sir please give me some hits for this...

Comment: i am not sure why you iterating it outside the <s:url> tag since the value you will get is the last assigned to the variables, moreover can you describe what is 'view' and from where this value is coming from? do you want multiple URL's as seems from your code? and last but not least i am not **Sir**

Comment: If you have an action class, it would be good to post that... what error are you getting? We can definitely help in terms of the view but considering this weird mixed syntax I would have much less of a headache if the action class were provided and you explained what you wanted in the view in plain English (possibly with pseudo code).

Comment: Pseudocode..Days are displayed in the the jsp page from java class....

       If "Add day" Button click then
              1 increment in days will happen,and same will be display......
      Now it is displaying in normal form<in td tags> but i want to apply it in <SJ:tabPannel> <sj:tab>......
       How can i do this?